# How to import highlightjs

Tags: typescript, highlightjs

VS Code extensions are typically written with Typescript. I'm implementing an extension for printing and I'd like to use [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) to do syntax colouring.

So in we bring it

```
npm i highlightjs -s
```

and the inevitable

```
npm i @types/highlight.js -s
```

at which point we find that we have code completion in VS Code and we can write things like

```
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';
...
let text = editor.document.getText();
let html = hljs.highlightAuto(text);
```

and it compiles and runs... until we do something that triggers an attempt to load `highlight.js`. At this point an error occurs.

> Error: Cannot find module 'highlight.js' extensionHostProcess.js:331
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)

A stickybeak in `../node_modules/highlightjs` reveals that we have `highlight.pack.js` and `highlight.pack.min.js` but no `highlight.js`

Very confusing.  Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `highlightjs` and `highlight.js` packages both exist, but `@types/highlight.js` must be paired with the `highlight.js` package.